# I have automated Soap request via Rest Assured code, but its written that Rest assured API can only be used for rest service

Tags: java, soapui, postman, rest-assured

Here is my code
public class xmlreq extends TestBase  {

```
@Test
public void buildRequest()
{
    logger.info("starting");
    RestAssured.baseURI="http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo";
    
    httpRequest=    RestAssured.given();
    String b= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:web=\"http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo\">\r\n" + 
            "   <soapenv:Header/>\r\n" + 
            "   <soapenv:Body>\r\n" + 
            "      <web:CapitalCity>\r\n" + 
            "         <web:sCountryISOCode>IND</web:sCountryISOCode>\r\n" + 
            "      </web:CapitalCity>\r\n" + 
            "   </soapenv:Body>\r\n" + 
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";
    httpRequest.header("Content-Type","text/xml");
    httpRequest.body(b);
    
    
    
    response=   httpRequest.request(Method.POST, "/CountryInfoService.wso?wsdl");
    
    Assert.assertTrue(response.getBody().asString()!=null);
    System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());
    
}

@Test(enabled=true)
public void validate()
{
    String a = response.getBody().asString();
    Assert.assertTrue(a.contains("New Delhi"));     
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the error message you are getting.

Comment: No its working fine but curious  can rest assured API handle wsdl